# optimize web service client side performance?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, service

I am using the automatically generated proxy for a ASP.Net asmx web service. I find when send HttpWebRequest to my web server, it is the throughput from client side is very good (very big number). But when using the automatically generater proxy, it is very slow. I want to know some general ways to optimize the performance of client, especially increase throughput. If it could be improved by change some configuration at server side, it would also be great!

BTW: I am using asynchronous method call of the web method of the ASP.Net web service.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

The best way to increase the proxy class construction speed is to ship an `XmlSerializers` assembly along your binary. It's generated by Visual Studio if you choose in the project properties or it can be manually generated by [`sgen.exe` tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk3w6240(VS.80).aspx) shipped with .NET.

Comment: Thanks Mehrdad, I am using automatically generated proxy code by using Add Web Reference function from VSTS. In this case, I should run sgen on which DLL?

Comment: Another comment, I think it could only improve performance for the 1st time if I made a lot of sequencial calls to web service from web service proxy?

Comment: Yes, I think it'll only affect the first time performance. Nope you don't need to run sgen separately if VS generates it for you.

Comment: Thanks, I think it is not what I need. The 1st time performance degrade is not important and I care about the long run client's overall long term performance throughput. Any idas?